# Where to Place My Package in Lumen Framework

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, lumen, lumen-5.2

If I want to use some custom class in Lumen, where should I place them? The Laravel official document does not mention this in any of `application structure`, `service container` or `package development`. Actually I found the document quite confusing to some extents.

For example, I want to set up a service called `Invitation`, I know I need to register this class in `InvitationServiceProvider` but where should I place the `Invitation.php` which the actual class exists in? This package is used for some specific application thus I do not want to put it in composer packagist.

BTW, the version of Lumen Framework is 5.2.

Comment: Laravel **intentionally** doesn't enforce any rules because each project is different and there is no **one size fits all** when it comes to code structuring. So my advice is to place and group classes and other code in a way that make sense to you in the context of your application. The [Application Structure Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/structure) actually starts with this sentence: _"The default Laravel application structure is intended to provide a great **starting point** for both large and small applications"_. So that's just a starting point, the rest is up to you.

Comment: If you're really confused about where to start, consider the following: some people like to group things only by function, so all models go in a `models` dir, event listeners in a `listeners` dir, and so on. If you have large modules with lots of classes then you might want to group them ([one way to approach that](http://bit.do/bTdej)). Where to put things is a problem that bugs a lot of programmers, and for me naming my classes properly ([beware of `SomeManager`, `SomeService`, etc](http://bit.do/bTdeq)) makes it easier to group and structure them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally I created a folder named `Service` under `app` and just pull all the libraries inside...

Comment: I'm using the same approach. However, have you considered using a private repository so you avoid using packagist for your project-specific classes?

Comment: Yes but since what I want to put is just some simple codes like custom method to encrypt data and a static class file is enough for me. I may consider to use private repository when need to use some complicated package including Service Provider and custom view etc.